# how to combine two numpy arrays and form a new array of a new size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that have the same shape(4,1,2). 
How can I combine them and get a new array of size(8,1,2) with minimum lines of python code? Not changing values just put them together with A on the top B at the bottom.

```
    A=numpy.array([[[1,1]],
                   [[2,2]],
                   [[3,3]],
                   [[4,4]]]);


   B=numpy.array([[[5,5]],
                   [[6,6]],
                   [[7,7]],
                   [[8,8]]]);
```

Comment: I googled this "how to combine two numpy arrays" and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays I don't even know what numpy is and figured it out... lazy question

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) should do what you want:

```
numpy.concatenate((A, B))
```

Comment: `numpy.vstack((A,B))` is another alternative

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.vstack()

```
numpy.vstack([A,B])
```