# Solving Vector ODE in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, physics, ode

Id like to thank whoever answers this in advance, as it is probably a stupid question and a waste of time to answer.

The given code takes the electromagnetic forces on a particle and supposedly plots its trajectory, but I cant figure out how to use rk4 with vectors. Feel like my function is set up wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import inv, det, eig
from numpy.random import randn

def rk4(f, x0, dt):
    tn = 0
    xn = x0

    while True:        
        yield tn,xn

        k1 = dt*f(tn,xn)
        k2 = dt*f(tn+dt/2,xn+k1/2)
        k3 = dt*f(tn+dt/2,xn+k2/2)
        k4 = dt*f(tn+dt,xn+k3)

        xn = xn + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
        tn = tn + dt
#--------------------------------------------------------

def f(t,X):
    x,y,z,xv,yv,zv = X
    v = [xv,yv,zv]
    E = [k*x , k*y , -2*z]
    a = (q/m)*(E+np.cross(v,B))
    Xdot = np.array([v,a])
    return Xdot

q , m , B , k = 1.6e-19, 40, [0,0,1], 10e+4


X0 = np.array([0.001 , 0 , 0.001 , 100 , 0 , 0]) 
solver = rk4(f,X0,10e-7) 

ts = []
Xs = []
for t,X in solver:
    ts.append(t)
    Xs.append(X[0])
    if t > 0.001:
        break


#Xs = np.array(Xs) 
#plt.figure()
#plt.plot(ts,Xs)
```

Id really appreciate any tips or hints
I suspect the problem stems from the way iv set up the function, as the code crashes once it tries to run it through rk4.

Comment: Look at your full error stack, add a `print` before the line that crashes to debug... find out that `B=1`. How do you expect to take the cross product between a 3-vector and a scalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not apply vector arithmetic to simple python lists, thus convert the lists first into numpy arrays. You need to return a flat vector, not a matrix, thus use array concatenation to join the two parts.

```
def f(t,X):
    x,y,z,xv,yv,zv = X
    v = np.array([xv,yv,zv])  #  or v = X[3:]
    E = np.array([k*x , k*y , -2*z]) # or E=k*X[:3]; E[2]=-2*X[2]
    a = (q/m)*(E+np.cross(v,B))
    Xdot = np.concatenate([v,a])
    return Xdot
```

For the last change see [Concatenating two one-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9236926/3088138)