# Python : concatenate 2 arrays with 1 empty

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

It's strange I don't find anything on this. I want to concatenate 2 arrays that come from a bigger one.

For example :

```
first_array = []

second_array = [1, 2]
```

My desired outcome:

```
a = first_array + second_array = [1, 2]
```

It is a possible case of my problem and `+` operator leads to :

> *** ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8042,) (0,)

extends and appends can't be computed either...

Any tips to accept to concatenate 2 array with an empty one ? Everything is working well in other cases with '+' op.

Thanks you :)

In this post : [Concatenating two one-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays) they talk about concatenate but I would like to have another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using normal lists it should work. Otherwise, if you're using numpy arrays, you can do this:

```
a = list(first_array)+list(second_array)
```

Comment: It works well with this, thanks you !