# Transform array of arrays to a single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to expand a list of arrays into a single array, so for example:

```
a = [array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6]), array([7,8,9,])]
```

To become:

```
a = [array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two one-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert list to np.array and then flatten inside the list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9,])]
>>> [np.array(arr).flatten()]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
list.extend
```

It will work
Maybe you want this

```
from numpy import array
k=[array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6]), array([7,8,9,])]
l=[]
for i in range(len(k)):
  l.extend(k[i])
print(array(l))
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reshape of Numpy to do it:-

```
a=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
print("Before:" , a)
import numpy as np
a=np.reshape(a,9)
print("After:",a)
```

The output:

```
Before: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
After: [1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Hope this is what you want.