# Concatenate Multidimensional Numpy array with 1D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have two numpy arrays (letters from the EMNIST dataset):

```
import scipy .io
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DATA_DIR + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
y_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]
```

With the following dimensions:

`X_train.shape` = (124800, 784)

`y_train.shape` = (124800, 1)

Now, I want to concatenate the two, so that the new shape would be: (124800, 785).

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays) link, I tried:

```
np.concatenate((X_train.shape, y_train.shape), axis = 0)
```

However, that results in the following shape: array([124800,    784, 124800,      1]).

How can I 'paste' `y_train` behind `X_train` so that the shape will be (124800, 785)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate two arrays, you have to concatenate the data inside the arrays, not the shape. Furthermore you want to concatenate on the second ("short") axis, which is `axis=1`:

```
np.concatenate((X_train, y_train), axis=1)
```