# Concatenating two numpy arrays side by side

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to concatenate two numpy arrays side by side

```
np1=np.array([1,2,3])
np2=np.array([4,5,6])
```

I need `np3` as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` with the same shape, how to achieve this?

Comment: [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two one-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `concatenate` you have to pass `axis` as `None`

```
In [9]: np1=np.array([1,2,3])
   ...: np2=np.array([4,5,6])

In [10]: np.concatenate((np1,np2), axis=None)
Out[10]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: I suggest to set axis to "1" for safety, imagine the case you did it on array of 2 or more row

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.hstack` made for this:

```
np3 = np.hstack((np1,np2))
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```