# How to concatenate numba lists

Tags: python, list, concatenation, numba

I replaced a Python list with a Numba int32 list and its concatenation behaviour wasn't as expected.

For example in Python: if a = [1,2,3] and b = [4,5,6] then a += b gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

In Numba, on the other hand:
if a = numba.int32([1,2,3]) and b = numba.int32([4,5,6]) then a += b gives array([5, 7, 9], dtype=int32).

Is there a way I can easily concatenate Numba lists as we do in Python? or is the only solution to write a function that loops over the two arrays and creates another one?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two one-dimensional NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236926/concatenating-two-one-dimensional-numpy-arrays)

Comment: I just figured out that if I used List from numba.typed, it behaves as you would expect with the increment operator. Funnily you can't add two numba.typed lists though. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: In reply to Woodford's question, thanks for the suggestion, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me that Numba and Numpy arrays were compatible. I'm keeping my question since it might help others to whom might not be aware of the compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the concatenate function. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

```
import numpy as np
a = numba.int32([1,2,3])
b = numba.int32([4,5,6])
c = np.concatenate((a,b))
```

Comment: Accepted this over Sup's correct answer since the method works on numba.typed List too.

Comment: @user3353185 It did not work for numba.typed.List. At least with numba==0.56.0, I am receiving the following... TypeError: np.concatenate(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use `list()`

```
a = numba.int32(list(a)+list(b))
```